# Print multiple entries to .txt from tkinter when using Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Newbie to python. Learning how the Lambda function works with printing. I have managed to output the print to a .txt document using sys.stdout, but when I do I am only getting the last variable in the fields. How are all fields captured? What am I missing?

```
    from tkinter import *

    fields = 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Organization', 'Tax Exeption',

    def fetch(entries):
        for entry in entries:
            field = entry[0]
            text = entry[1].get()
            sys.stdout = open('file.txt', 'w')
            print('%s: "%s"' % (field, text))
            sys.stdout.close()

    def makeform(root, fields):
        entries = []
        for field in fields:
            row = Frame(root)
            lab = Label(row, width=15, text=field, anchor='w')
            ent = Entry(row)
            row.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)
            lab.pack(side=LEFT)
            ent.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=YES, fill=X)
            entries.append((field, ent))
        return entries

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        root = Tk()
        root.title('Order Info')
        ents = makeform(root, fields)
        root.bind('<Return>', (lambda event, e=ents: fetch(e)))
        b1 = Button(root, text='Print',
                    command=(lambda e=ents: fetch(e)))
        b1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
        b2 = Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit)
        b2.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
        root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are opening the file each time in the for loop. You want to open it once, write all then close.

```
def fetch(entries):
    sys.stdout = open('file.txt', 'w')
    for entry in entries:
        field = entry[0]
        text = entry[1].get()
        print('%s: "%s"' % (field, text))
    sys.stdout.close()
```

Another problem is that by opening the file in write mode it will truncate the file. More info on file modes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1466036/4831822).

So if you want to be able to add multiple groups of data to the same file you will need to use the mode `a` to append to the file.

```
sys.stdout = open('file.txt', 'a')
```

Additionally, you can also do without sys.

```
def fetch(entries):
    with open('file.txt', 'a') as fout:
        for field, entry in entries:
            text = entry.get()
            fout.write('{} "{}"\n'.format(field, text))
            #fout.write(f'{field} "{text}"\n') #3.6+
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it had to be something simple I was overlooking.